# Limit array results and increment through when button is clicked

Tags: php

What I am hoping to do is display the first 5 items (Stage1 - Stage5) from the array when the page is loaded. To the side I will have two images one arrow pointing up and one arrow down. If the down arrow is clicked the array is incremented to display (Stage2 - Stage6). Another click on the down arrow the screen would display (Stage3 - Stage7). Then the up arrow does the same but the opposite direction.

With the code I have below I can manually add "1" to $var1 and $var2 or subtract 1 when needed, save and refresh the browser to get the effect I am looking for. I just can't seem to figure out how to do the increments of $var1 and $var2 and then refresh the page, all automatically when the arrow images are clicked.

I am new so I could be completely off with what I have but hopefully it at least helps show what I want to do.

```
<?php

$stage_name=array
("Stage1","Stage2","Stage3","Stage4",
"Stage5","Stage6","Stage7","Stage8",
"Stage9","Stage10","Stage11","Stage12",
"Stage13","Stage14","Stage15","Stage16");

?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$var1=0; $var2=5;
for($list=$var1; $list<$var2; $list++)
{
    foreach($stage_name as $stage_index => $stage_item)
    {
        if ($stage_index==$list)
            print("$stage_item<br />");
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: welcome, and well formed question! to help you i would need the code where you add the images to the page. they're namely the key! :)

Comment: Whatever you're clicking on would have to pass in a 'page number' for your code to use as a starting point. Then `$var1 = $_GET['start']` and `$var2 = $var1 + 5`

Comment: <form>
    <input type="image" src="arrowup.png" alt="Up" name="up" /> 
    <input type="image" src="arrowdown.png" alt="Down" name="down" /> 
    </form>

Comment: That is as far as I had gone with the image submit buttons. Sorry I should have added those to begin with. To answer your question davogotland it is actually for work. We didn't have anyone who knows PHP so I said I would do it. I think this stuff is fun and jumping in and doing it is a good way to learn.

Comment: @KeithSchenker alright, i see. sounds fun! i posted my take on a pedagogical answer. i hope you can use all these answers to help you understand the solution you need to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stageNames = array("Stage1", "Stage2", "Stage3", "Stage4",
                    "Stage5", "Stage6", "Stage7", "Stage8",
                    "Stage9", "Stage10", "Stage11", "Stage12",
                    "Stage13", "Stage14", "Stage15", "Stage16");

$offset  = isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;
$perPage = 5;

if ($offset > 0) {
    printf('<a href="here.php?offset=%d">Up</a>', $offset - 1);
}

foreach (array_slice($stageNames, $offset, $perPage) as $stageName) {
    echo $stageName . '<br>';
}

if ($offset + $perPage < count($stageNames)) {
    printf('<a href="here.php?offset=%d">Down</a>', $offset + 1);
}
```

Comment: I would say that this code is a bit to complicated for a complete beginner. Neither Ternary Operators nor printf are especially clear at first glance. Innovative use of array_slice but is there a reason to use that instead of a for-loop when we know that there won't be an Associative array? Or is it just to be bullet proof?

Comment: Those two things are really easy to lookup and learn. I don't think there's a need to go easy with this kind of stuff on anyone. :) I'll even throw in links to the documentation: http://www.php.net/printf and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary And `array_slice` is just a nice, simple way to do this.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the help. I can follow the code and see what is happening. I don't understand it completely but I will definitely research it so I can learn from it. I have been able to edit it to meet my needs so I am happy. Again thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1):

here are some instructions that intend to make it fun for you to learn and to solve your puzzle!

first, let me point out something in your code that is unnecessary :) to print the desired indexes, you don't have to do the inner loop. you can just reference the indexes in your array:

```
$stage_item[4]
```

that would make your loop look like this:

```
for($list=$var1; $list<$var2; $list++)
{
    print("{$stage_item[$list]}<br />");
}
```

note the curly braces! they're needed since the expression now is a bit more complex, and php needs help to keep the pieces apart.

**about the incrementation**

you have to send notes and messages between the page calls. i mean, you will have to somehow make the page aware of what happened last time it was called. we will do this through the use of url parameters.

you see, you can receive parameters from the url! in the url, these parameters are formulated as key/value pairs.

```
start=2
end=7
```

they are separated by ampersands

```
start=2&end=7
```

the key/value pairs start after a question mark

```
mysite.com/url.php?start=2&end=7
```

*here we've sent start and end (these are made up, just like var1 and var2 from your example) to the page url.php*

these are then fetched with the magic variable `$_GET`. it's an array, and it magically has the keys from your keys in the url. so to get start, you do

```
$var1 = $_GET['start'];
```

note the quotes. these are there since the keys in this case are strings, as opposed to the earlier example, where the keys were numbers (aka integers). now, how can we let such urls be activated from our page? well, you have the images, right? (and don't use a form with input fields here, use the img tag instead)

```
<img src='arrowup.png' />
```

just put that in an anchor tag

```
<a href='the_same_page_youre_already_on.php?start=1&end=6'><img src="arrowup.png" /></a>
```

now for the tricky part.. how do you know what numbers to place in the url? for the uparrow, they're one smaller than what you already have. and for down arrow, they're one larger.

make sure you put in checks that stops the indexes from being too small (lesser than 0) or too large (larger than 15 i suppose). and also, check that start and end are actually set. and if not, give them initial values.

```
if(isset($_GET['start'])) { //check if we actually got a value
    $var1 = $_GET['start'];
} else {
    $var1 = 0;
}
```

and same for end ($var2). then, calculate new variables for the adjacent pages.

```
$next_start = $var1 + 1;
$next_end = $var2 + 1;
$previous_start = $var1 - 1;
$previous_end = $var - 1;
```

use your variables to print what you need to print. print the arrows, but use the next_start/previous_end variables as values for the different parameters in the link.

Comment: I got it to work with one of the other answers but I will go through your answer also so I can learn an alternate way. The more I can learn the better. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

first off you need to set $var1 and $var2 based on what a user has clicked (or if thay haven't clicked anywhere) such as

```
if($_GET['start'])}
    $var1 = $_GET['start']
} else {
    $var1 = 0;
}
$var2 = $var1+5;
```

With this your code will read a value from your url such as yourdomain.com/display.php?start=1 (this will set $var1 to 1) and that is all you need to get your current code to output the correct 5 elements. But your code is very inefficient. With the values 0->5 this will happen:

```
For loop starts with $list = 0:
    Foreach goes trough each of the elements in the array
        First element in the Foreach loop maches $stage_index==$list
        Second element in the Foreach loop doesnt mach $stage_index==$list
        ....
        16:th element in the foreach loop doesnt mach $stage_index==$list
    Foreach loop ends
For loop increments and continues with $list = 1
    Foreach goes trough each of the elements in the array
        First element in the Foreach loop doesnt mach $stage_index==$list
        Second element in the foreach loop matches $stage_index==$list
        Third element in the Foreach loop doesnt mach $stage_index==$list
        ....
        16:th element in the foreach loop doesnt mach $stage_index==$list
    Foreach loop ends
For loop increments and continues with $list = 2
....
For loop reaches $list = $var2 and the loop ends
```

With this construct you loop trough the array 80 times to echo 5 values (so 75 times are without any benefit whatsoever).
The solution is quite simple but I will let you figure it out by your self since you will learn more that way. Everything you need to solve that problem can be found online in the php manual ([http://php.net/](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)) and on tutorial sites such as [http://www.w3schools.com/](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) (which actually is a great page to start learning about php and html).

Comment: www.w3schools.com is where I have learned the little bit I know now. I will also check out php.net also. Thank you very much